# "spool off; /" significance of '/' post spool off

Tags: sqlplus, ksh

Please help me with the below concern I am facing.

I have some existing shell scripts that run daily at regular intervals to spool some data into a text file and send it to another system.

Now i have made some changes to those scripts and the spooling which used to take 6 hours, now the same is taking more than 8 hours.

I have read "/" in the script usually executes the previous sql statement.
So by the code below, is the sql query being called twice?

I am new to this and sorry if i am being Naive, any help related to the same is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    ORACLE_HOME=/pprodi1/oracle/9.2.0; export ORACLE_HOME;
    Script_Path=<path>
    dt=`date '+%y%m%d%H%M'`

    find $Script_Path/testing_spool* -mtime +3 | xargs  rm -f { }

    cd $Script_Path

    sqlplus -s uname/pwd@db_name<<EOF1>/dev/null

    set echo off
    set head off
    set pages 0
    set feedback off
    set pause off
    set colsep "    "
    set verify off
    set termout off
    set linesize 3000
    set trimspool on

    spool $Script_Path/testing_spool.dat

    SELECT column_name
      FROM table_name
     WHERE created_date > SYSDATE - 1
       AND col1 = '126'
       AND col2 = 'N'
       AND col3 = 6;

    spool off;

    /

    EOF1

    cat testing_spool.dat > testing_spool_$dt.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your query will be executed twice, once while the spool is active and then again after it has been turned off.

As you mentioned, the `/` [executes whatever is currently in the SQL buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm), which will still contain your query. The `spool off` is a client command and does not affect the SQL buffer.

If you run your script without the output redirect `>/dev/null` on line 10, or redirect to a file instead if you expect a lot of output, then you will see the query results repeated.

---

Incidentally, `set termout off` isn't doing anything in your script because you're running it as a heredoc. If you had the statements in a script file and ran that with `start` or `@` then it would suppress the output, but [as the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG075):

> ECHO does not affect the display of commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating system.

You could potentially create a .sql file, run that, and then delete it - all within your shell script. You may not see much benefit, but it would mean you didn't need to hide all output with that redirect, which would make it harder to diagnose failures.